# Is Kotlin's mapIndexed guaranteed to retain ordering

Tags: kotlin, collections

`mapIndexed` on an array curiously returns a `List` not an array which isn't immediately intuitive.

I also noticed that [`kotlin.collections.mapIndexed` documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed.html) does not mention retention of ordering but [`kotlin.sequences.mapindexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/map-indexed.html) does.

I know that since it's not explicit in the doc, I shouldn't rely on it, but wondering if it's an intentional omission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is an omittion, it wouldn't be that practical to change the order of the elements, it would be highly unperformant.

The order is at least guaranteed by the implementation of the method as you can see below.
An enhanced for loop is used to loop through the whole collection and it applies the change only to the concerned index.

The fact that it returns a `List` is logical, since you'll get the same `List` back (actually a full copy - but with the same objects), only with the changes required.

```
/**
 * Applies the given [transform] function to each element and its index in the original collection
 * and appends the results to the given [destination].
 * @param [transform] function that takes the index of an element and the element itself
 * and returns the result of the transform applied to the element.
 */
public inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.mapIndexedTo(destination: C, transform: (index: Int, T) -> R): C {
    var index = 0
    for (item in this)
        destination.add(transform(checkIndexOverflow(index++), item))
    return destination
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Order is retained in the results. 
Check out my code here - changing the first item in the list:

```
val convertedResults = mutableListOf<DisplayItem>()

myList.mapIndexedNotNullTo(convertedResults) { index, item ->
        val member = DisplayItem(item)
        if (member.id == "id_007") {
            // add it first in the list 
            convertedResults.add(0, member)
            null
        } else
            member
}
```

This works well. But I don't know how to measure the performance here. Tell me what do you think about this code.

Answer (score 0):

An indication that the order is retained is also in [/libraries/stdlib/test/collections/IterableTests.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/56672c2564ed602927c961d1826295b1072955e4/libraries/stdlib/test/collections/IterableTests.kt) (link to latest revision in `master` at this time) of the official Kotlin repository

```
abstract class IterableTests<T : Iterable<String>>(val createFrom: (Array<out String>) -> T, val empty: T) {
    fun createFrom(vararg items: String): T = createFrom(items)

    val data = createFrom("foo", "bar")
```

[...]

```
    @Test
    fun mapIndexed() {
        val shortened = data.mapIndexed { index, value -> value.substring(0..index) }
        assertEquals(2, shortened.size)
        assertEquals(listOf("f", "ba"), shortened)
}
```

So the test also assumes the same order for output. This is odd by the way as this code is not only used for testing `List` and others but also for testing an unordered `Set`.

Similar code is used for testing `mapIndexed` on arrays of all types.